# WooCommerce Display all Products Shortcode with Pagination

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm using Woocommerce and am looking for some advice on how to go about display all products with pagination on a single page. I've seen some other inquiries here on Stack Overflow but didn't come across a definitive answer. I checked around the web and have only come across plugin-based solutions which isn't what I'm looking for. Does anyone here know a way to use just shortcodes with the right parameters to achieve this. I'd like to display this information chronologically as well. Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out I could use the built in woo commerce settings to display all products with pagination. (Woocommerce > Settings > Products > Shop Page) Didn't need to use shortcode to begin with.